# Finding the value of $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ in the equation $16^n-25\times 12^{n-1}+9^n=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $n$ is satisfy the equation $16^n-25\times 12^{n-1}+9^n=0$. Find the value of $n$.

Here is my work:

$$16^n-2\times12\times 12^{n-1}+9^n=12^{n-1}$$

$$(4^n-3^n)^2=12^{n-1}$$
For $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$ we can see the LHS is an odd number and RHS is odd only for $n=1$. But for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^-$ we have fractions in both sides of the equation. I don't know how to check if there are answers for negative values of $n$.

Comment: Note that $n=1$ is a solution....

Comment: @Alan I recognized it but forgot to explicitly mention in my post!

Comment: I added the reason why negative $n$ won't work in an answer once I realized that

Comment: Put $a=4^n,b=3^n$ then you have $12(a-b)^2=ab$, a quadratic in $a$ or $b$, so you can solve for it.

Comment: If $n=-m$, you get fractions.  What is the denominator on both sides ?

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks! I just solved a quadratic for $\frac ab$ and got the answer.

Comment: @Soheil Nice to hear that, that's also a good strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original expression $16^n-25\times 12^{n-1}+9^n=0$ when taken $\dfrac{1}{12}$ out common reduces to $\dfrac{1}{12}(4\cdot 3^n-3 \cdot 4^n)(3^{n+1}-4^{n+1})=0$

This results in 2 cases:

Case 1:

$(3^{n+1}-4^{n+1})=0 \implies 3^{n+1}=4^{n+1}$

This is one possible when both have power $0$

So $n+1=0 \implies n=-1$

Case 2:

$ (4\cdot 3^n-3 \cdot 4^n)=0 \implies 4 \cdot 3^n=3 \cdot 4^n $

If you try to see deep you will notice that when $n=1$ only then the equation is satisfied.

So $n=-1,1$

Edit: In case you failed here is other solution-

Take $a=4^n, b=3^n$ and yay there you get quadratic $12(a-b)^2=ab$. Just solve this and get your answer

Comment: In case you have any doubt leave it here

Comment: $4 \cdot 3^n=3 \cdot 4^n \implies 3^{n-1} = 4^{n-1}$ and so the only solution is $n = 1$ for case $2$, not sure why one would have to see deep after you already simplified the expression.

Comment: @Jitendra Singh Can you please elaborate on how you factored the original expression?

Comment: @MathLover I know for maximum it would be one sight but maybe if someone future reader has problem otherwise there is no main reason of using deep

Comment: @Soheil sorry there was a typo over there is it clear now?

Comment: @JitendraSingh Thanks, I asked for explanation on how you factored the expression.

Comment: $$16^n-25\times 12^{n-1}+9^n\\4^{2n}-(3^2+4^2)\times (3)^{n-1}(4)^{n-1}+3^{2n}\\4^{2n}-3^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}4^{n+1}+3^{2n}\\4^{n+1+n-1}-3^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}4^{n+1}+3^{n+1+n-1}\\4^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}4^{n+1}+3^{n+1}3^{n-1}\(3^{n-1}-4^{n-1})(3^{n+1}-4^{n+1})\bigg(\frac{3^n}{3}-\frac{4^n}{4}\bigg)(3^{n+1}-4^{n+1})$$

Comment: @Soheil above comment shows the method please don't take the \ red colour sign

Comment: $$16^n-25\times 12^{n-1}+9^n\\4^{2n}-(3^2+4^2)\times (3)^{n-1}(4)^{n-1}+3^{2n}\\4^{2n}-3^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}4^{n+1}+3^{2n}\\4^{n+1+n-1}-3^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}4^{n+1}+3^{n+1+n-1}\\4^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n+1}4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}4^{n+1}+3^{n+1}3^{n-1}\(3^{n-1}-4^{n-1})(3^{n+1}-4^{n+1})\\\bigg(\frac{3^n}{3}-\frac{4^n}{4}\bigg)(3^{n+1}-4^{n+1})$$